# DAG run marked as success while task failed

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have some `PythonOperator` in my `DAG` which time to time throws error therefore simply it goes into except statement and entire process is stopped due to that. What i do not understand is my dag run is marked as success. Can anyone explains that to me please as i thought if code inside task throws an error the dag should be marked as failed, not? Why `dag` is marked success?

**DAG (cutted):**

```
import time
import datetime
import json
import pprint
import requests
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator

def my_main(**kwargs):
    try:
        ....
     except:
        print("Error:", pprint.pformat(traceback.format_exc(), indent=1))


dag = DAG(
    'my_main', 
    description='my_main', 
    start_date=days_ago(0), 
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False
)
task_checker = PythonOperator(task_id='task_checker_my_main', provide_context=True, python_callable=my_main, dag=dag)
```

Comment: can you please share the dag

Comment: @ozs see mian post again - i cutted project's code as not required. When error appear and goes to `except` inside `my_main` function the dag run is marked as success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise Exception. you "swallow" the real exception so the function ends with no error . just raise exception after the print.

```
def my_main(**kwargs):
try:
    ....
 except:
    print("Error:", pprint.pformat(traceback.format_exc(), indent=1))
    raise AirflowException("your message")
```

Comment: If I would not have `try except` and there would be an error  will the `dag` status be failed or not? So by means is it like `except` as u said `swallow` the error and without that task would be `failed`? Am my understanding correct?

Comment: right, if you won't have try except and you would get an exception the task would fail.

Comment: so even if i would replace your AirflowException by example this: raise Exception("Date provided can't be in the past") the task also would fail right? When then there is right to throw exeptions of type AirflowException?

Comment: yes, even better to throw other exception to mention that its our code problem and airflow's.- sorry, if confused in this example with it

Comment: i see, nevertheless i still do not get what's the right way i mean for which cases can we throw specificly AirflowException ?

Comment: I think only if you implement airflow component like operator/plugins but not inside a task that has errors relevant to your business logic